# What is the solution for data recovery of Google Bookmarks?

Tags: google, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

In Google Contacts, we are able to do a restore of our contacts (data) in case we accidentally deleted all our data or something bad happens.

So I am assured that as long as I can login to Google Contacts at elast once every 30 days, my data is  sort of safe.

However I could not find a way to do this in Google Bookmarks. Like say I woke up today and find all my data messed up, I would like to restore to the "state" I have yesterday.

What is the solution (external solution would be fine as well) for data recovery of Google Bookmarks ?

Comment: Are you talking about bookmarks stored in Google Chrome or stored at google.com/bookmarks ?

Comment: @Barry Yep google.com/bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

In google bookmarks there is an "Export bookmarks" feature that will save your bookmarks to your computer.

Comment: But that's not a *real* solution..

Comment: That loses the labels, arguably the most important feature of bookmarking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is undocumented method to extract all the metadata, including labels, for your Google Bookmarks:

Simply fetch this URL, which generates XML of your first 10000 bookmarks:

```
http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000
```

This is what the first part of the file looks like:

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
<bookmarks>
<bookmark>
<title>SQLObject</title>
<url>http://www.sqlobject.org/</url>
<timestamp>1354202405670816</timestamp>
<id>6580515553737151351</id>
<labels>
<label>python</label>
<label>databases</label>
<label>sql</label>
<label>programming</label>
<label>orm</label>
<label>software_development</label>
<label>library</label>
<label>framework</label>
<label>@delicious_export</label>
</labels>
</bookmark>
```

This is only a partial answer, because you can't import bookmarks in the same format.  You could use a script to submit appropriate [post requests](http://www.mmartins.com/mmartins/googlebookmarksapi/) to re-generate your bookmarks with labels.